# Why my ajax function isn't asynchronous and refreshes the page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

what i'm trying to do here is having a button on my page that alert some data without refreshing the page (the data is a password that's why i don't want it to be written in the code).

My actual page works fine so far,
first part of the page:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['id']))
    header('location: index.php');
else
{
    $id = strip_tags($_SESSION['id']);
    $username = strip_tags($_SESSION['username']);
    $role = strip_tags($_SESSION['role']);

    require('config/functions.php');

    if (isset($_POST['idSite']) AND !empty($_POST['idSite'])) {
        $idSite = htmlspecialchars($_POST['idSite']);

        $connexionInfos = getConnexionInfos($idSite);
    }
}?>
```

the second part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Telem MCS</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#passCo").click(function(){
            var idTelem = <?= $idSite ?>;
            $.post("config/get_pass.php",
            {
              searchFor: idTelem
            },
            function(data,status){
              alert("Password: " + data);
            });
          });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="tabs_content">
        <div class="tab_content" id="connexion">
            <div class="form_info">
                <form>
                    <div id="except_procedure">
                    <?php foreach($connexionInfos as $connexionInfo): ?>
                        <div class="form-style-2">
                            <label for="field1"><span>Type de connexion </span>
                                <select name="field1" class="select-field" disabled="disabled">
                                    <option value=""><?= $connexionInfo->TYPECONNEXION ?></option>
                                </select>
                            </label>
                            <label for="field2"><span>Configuration VM </span>
                                <input type="text" class="input-field" name="field2" value="<?= $connexionInfo->TYPEVM ?>" disabled="disabled"/>
                            </label>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <label for="field5"><span>PASSWORDS</span>
                                <button id="passCo">PASS</button>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    <?php foreach($connexionInfos as $connexionInfo): ?>
                        <div class="form-style-2">
                            <label for="field6"><span>Procedure </span>
                                <textarea name="field6" class="textarea-field" disabled="disabled"><?= $connexionInfo->PROCEDURE ?></textarea>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And finally the "get_pass.php" file that's supposed to call the data in the background:

```
<?php

require('connect.php');
if (isset($_POST['searchFor'])) {
    $idTelem = strip_tags($_POST['searchFor']);
    $req = $bdd->prepare("SELECT NOMTELEM FROM histotelem WHERE IDHISTOTELEM = '".$idTelem."'");
    $req->execute(array($idTelem));
    $keys = $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $req->closeCursor();
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        echo $key->NOMTELEM;
     } 
}
else {
    echo "oups !";
}
```

So this works fine, i can click the button, i get the data in the alert, but once i validate the alert, the page is refreshing and i dont get my original displayed datas anymore...

Hope someone has an idea of what's going on here

Comment: Side note: I hope you're not thinking that `strip_tags()` will help against an SQL injection; it won't. Use a prepared statement, since you're already using PDO. Edit: Same thing goes for `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: Also you have multiple IDs if your loop more than once - ID must be UNIQUE

Comment: htmlspecialchars() would work better?

Comment: @JonathanBlt See my edited comment; reload it. Same thing ;-)

Comment: How to prevent [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Also is $idSite a number? If not, use quotes `var idTelem = "<?= $idSite ?>";`

Comment: Plus, what you have now `prepare/execute`, can be narrowed down to just using `query()`. But that isn't a good idea since you should use a prepared statement. See the manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php - The `prepare/execute` right now, doesn't constitute as a prepared statement.

Answer (score 3):

Because the default `type` of [`button`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-button-element) elements is `"submit"`, so the browser is submitting the form.

To prevent it, accept the event object as the first parameter in your `click` handler and call `preventDefault` on it:

```
$("#passCo").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // ...
});
```

Alternatively, you could add `type="button"` to the `button`, but then the button won't work on browsers with JavaScript turned off. (I don't know whether you're handling that case anyway, but...)

Comment: Better to use ` $("form").on("submit...` than `$("..submitbutton").on("click"`

Comment: @mplungjan - Hmmm, quite possibly, yeah.